# Eigenvalue of loosely defined matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $\left\|\lambda\right\|_2$.
 $\lambda(=a+bi)$ is eigenvalue of A. $\;\;\left\|\lambda\right\|_2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ .
$ A=I-\frac{2}{u^Tu}uu^T,\;\;\;(non-zero)\;u\in \mathbb{R}^n, \;\;\;A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}  $

---

I'm not sure how to find A so that I can find the determinant of it.
All I could think was $\;\;u^Tu= \left\|u\right\|^2 \;\;$ and $\;\;uu^T$ is symmetric.
and A would have a form like this.
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & ? &? \\
? & -1 & ? \\
? & ? & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Since it's symmetrical it'll have real eigenvalues.

Now, how should I proceed?

Comment: 1st) Calculate $Au$; 2nd) Calculate $A^TA$ $(=A^2)$. That gives you the full eigen-structure.

Comment: um... I'm not sure what you mean. What do I get from Au and $A^TA$ ?

Comment: $A^TA=\mathbf{1}$ says that $A$ is orthogonal. Therefore it has an orthogonal eigensystem. Actually you can use any base for the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span}\{u\}$ to complete the eigensystem of $A$ because $A$ acts as identity on the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span}\{u\}$ ($A$ is a [(Householder) reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics))). $u$ has eigenvalue -1 while the other eigenvectors correspond to the eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Many things in your comment confuse me. I'm bad at this haha;; let me ask you one by one. how is $A^TA$ equal to 1? when I imangine 3-by-3 identity matrix, I can't get 1. I get $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Didn't write 1, wrote $\mathbf{1}$ standing for the identity matrix. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: Ah, I'm not good enough to notice such things. Thanks, I'll try to understand your comment further.

Comment: Why does $A^TA$ equals $\mathbf{1}$?

Comment: $\left(I-\frac{2}{u^Tu}uu^T\right)\cdot\left(I-\frac{2}{u^Tu}uu^T\right)=??$

Comment: I didn't think $I-\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^2}uu^T+\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^4}uu^Tuu^T$ would equal 0. But it does. How is it so?

Comment: No. $I-\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^2}uu^T+\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^4}uu^Tuu^T=I$. It is not zero but the identity matrix as expected for orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I meant $-\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^2}uu^T+\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^4}uu^Tuu^T$ equals 0. yet I'm not sure how it does.

Comment: $uu^Tuu^T=\|u\|^2\cdot uu^T$ in the second term.

Comment: Thanks especially for your patience -_-;;;. Does it work like this? 
$A^TA=A\cdot A\;\;\; \mathbf{So,} \;\;uu^Tuu^T=uu\cdot uu^T=\left\|u\right\|^2uu^T\;\;$ and I'm not sure what you mean by 'u
 has eigenvalue -1 while the other eigenvectors correspond to the eigenvalue 1'

Comment: Yet if $u\cdot u$ is the scalar product. About the eigenvalues: 1st: $\left(I-2\frac{uu^T}{|u|^2}\right)u=??$; 2nd: If $v\perp u$, i.e., $v\cdot u = 0$ What does that imply for $\left(I-2\frac{uu^T}{|u|^2}\right)v$?

Comment: They would be -u and v. So without know it's householder reflection, I should be able to infer it's a reflection about a plane from $ \left( I-\frac{2}{u^Tu}uu^T \right)u=-u$ and conclude other eigenvalue would be -1 or 1 to solve this problem?

Comment: "Householder reflection" is just a name. The properties are really important and you arrived at the right solution just by deduction and recalculation. The actual thing that makes this question quite simple here is that $uu^T$ (the scalar factor does not matter much) is just a rank-1-update of the affected matrix (here the simple identity matrix). I recommend that you finally write up your own answer and accept it to close that question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to write what i've understood by the help of Tobias.

$A^TA=AA=\left(I-\frac{2}{u^Tu}uu^T \right)\left(I-\frac{2}{u^Tu}uu^T \right)=I-\frac{4}{u^Tu}uu^T+\frac{4}{(u^Tu)^2}uu^Tuu^T  $
$= I-\frac{4}{\left\|u^2\right\|}uu^T+\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^4}uu^Tuu^T=I-\frac{4}{\left\|u^2\right\|}uu^T+\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^4}\left\|u^2\right\|uu^T=I-\frac{4}{\left\|u^2\right\|}uu^T+\frac{4}{\left\|u\right\|^2}uu^T=I$

So, A is orthogonal matrix. *(I'm not sure why it matters though it means $det$ is $\pm$1)*
And,

$Au=\left(I-\frac{2}{u^Tu}uu^T \right)u=u-2u=-u$
It means A is a "reflection about a plane" transformation matrix, thus for a v($\perp u$), Av=v.
*(I wonder If I need to figure out eigenvectors would be orthonormal from the fact that A is symmetrical to get to this conclusion.)*

Eigenvalues of A is -1 and two 1.